# MS Word 2010, want to auto-italicize brackets and text within them

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, automation

I type and format a lot of files that require brackets and things within brackets to be italicized (like *[this]*). I know how to do it using find and replace, but I'm tired of doing it that way and hoping for something faster. Is there a way to make it so that the text just auto-italicizes as I type, maybe a macro? I tried recording a macro myself for this but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: (1) Map an unused F-key or Ctrl+Shift combination to a macro, and type that every time you type `]`.  (1b) Have the macro insert the `]` character itself; then you can type the triggering shortcut *instead* of typing `]`.  (2) [Running Macros Based on Keywords](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T012375_Running_Macros_Based_on_Keywords.html) says that you cannot trigger a macro by typing, but suggests having a macro that runs periodically (e.g., once per second) on a timer, and have it look at the text you typed since the last time it ran.

Answer (score -1):

You can write your document normally and when you're done typing perform a global replace for text in brackets, and replace it with the same text italicized:

1. Click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace dialog.
2. In the `Find what` field type `\[*\]` to find text in brackets.
3. Check the `Use wildcards` checkbox.
4. Leave the`Replace with` field empty.
5. Click the `Format` button, select `Font ...` from the menu and the set the font to `Italic`.
6. Click `Replace` to see each bracketed text being found and italicized, or `Replace All` to italicize all occurrences at once.

Here's a screenshot of the replace dialog in Word 2010 (it looks similar in other versions):

[image]

Comment: I know how to do that, but it's annoying to do it in every single file. I'm hoping for something faster/that requires fewer steps and clicks.